# Override method of module ActionController::Caching::Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actioncontroller

I want to override the `caching_allowed?` to accept caching a POST request based on some condition. How do I do that?

I have tried the below in a initializer file. But it does not work.

```
require "set"

module ActionController
  module Caching
    module Actions
      def caching_allowed?
        # condition
        # change code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Update:

This method is called using current controller object. So I just override the method inside the particular controller and it works.

Comment: Where is the origin method defined? What rails version do you use?

Comment: `ActionController::Caching::Actions` was removed from the code base way back in Rails 4. Why do you want to do this and why do you think a monkeypatch is the solution? If you have a legacy application I would just override the method in your ApplicationHelper or somewhere like that.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve but I would highly recommend `Module#prepend` rather than overwriting a method in rails. e.g. `module MyModule; def caching_allowed?; something? ? false : super; end;end` then `ActionController::Caching::Actions.send(:prepend, MyModule)`

Comment: @max I have a requirement to cache a action, but the action is configured as POST method to support 3rd party application. So I want to override the method to allow caching POST request only for this case.

Comment: I wouldn't use ActionController::Caching::Actions in the first place here as its not a future proof solution. It was just a nuclear option which didn't make sense. Isn't it possible to use the low level cache, SQL caching etc to handle any potential performance bottlenecks?

Comment: Not possible to use SQL cache as it involves no SQL queries. My requirement exactly is to cache the JSON response of the API with expiry of 1 hour and serve it from cache as the operation done inside is expensive. Also I need option to expire the cache on some condition. What do you recommend @max

Comment: Low level caching. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/rails-low-level-caching/